# How to run java program with ant

Tags: java, ant, build.xml

I am a complete noob in Java and I want to know how do you run a Java program after you use build.xml. I am using 'cmd' and I got the message BUILD SUCCESSFUL after compiling (?) Now what should I do to run the program?

Edit: it created a .war file.  How do I execute it?

Comment: Ant is used to build the source; if it has built then you need to execute your entry point. What kind of project have you built?

Comment: can you please post the command you entered into cmd to compile

Comment: command used /ant -buildfile C:\Users\Meh\Project

Comment: You should actually start [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: its an online Enterprise System

Answer (score 7):

I assume that this is a simple "Hello, World" Java program (**HelloWorld.java**) and that the **HelloWorld.java**, **build.xml** and the **HelloWorld.class** (to be generated) are in the current directory (**.**)

**HelloWorld.java** file :

```
public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window.
    System.out.println("Hello, World");
}

}
```

Create two **targets** : **compile** and **run** in your **build.xml** file :

```
<project name="Hello World" basedir=".">

<target name="compile">
       <javac srcdir="." includeantruntime="true" includes="HelloWorld.java" destdir="."></javac>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="compile">
       <java classname="HelloWorld" fork="true"></java>
</target>

</project>
```

Now you simply need to navigate to the current directory in your terminal and run :

```
ant run
```

Answer (score 0):

Not assuming everything is in the root directory, a far better solution is available on the apache ant page that parameterizes all the directories etc. and is a more general and practical answer. [Tutorial: Hello World with Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html)

```
<project name="Hello World" basedir=".">        
        <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
        <javac
            srcdir="src"
            destdir="build/classes"/>
        <!-- automatically detected -->
        <!-- obsolete; done via manifest tag -->
        <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
        <jar
            destfile="build/jar/HelloWorld.jar"

            basedir="build/classes">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="org.HelloWorld"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
        <java jar="build/jar/HelloWorld.jar" fork="true"/>
    
    <target name="compile">
           <javac includeantruntime="true" includes="HelloWorld.java"></javac>
    </target>           
    
    <target name="run" depends="compile">
           <java classname="bin/org/HelloWorld" fork="true"></java>      
        <echo message="Event Generator Finished."/>
    </target>
</project>
```